# Eclipse shows arrow on folder but the git repository is clean

Tags: git, eclipse

I have one silly question, You can see there is an arrow in eclipse in my project which states that something is changed in the folder. But my repository is clean and I am not sure what is wrong here. It is a git repository and if something is changed it shows the arrow in eclipse but I am not sure what wrong I did here.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: The dao folder has something changed]

Comment: Is your **Git** **Staging** view empty for this repo? Does the `git` CLI say it's clean? Can you show them?

Comment: What is the result of *git status* executed in a terminal in that folder?